# Getting the location of indices missing from secondary DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Please examine the commented text in the code below in order to understand the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

primary = pd.DataFrame(
    data = ['little','mary','had','a','swan'],
    index =pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-09-25 12:00:00', 
                           '2015-09-25 13:00:00',
                           '2015-09-25 14:00:00',
                           '2015-09-25 15:00:00',
                           '2015-09-25 16:00:00']),
    columns=['some_nonsense'])

secondary = pd.DataFrame(
    data = ['mommy',np.nan],
    index =pd.DatetimeIndex(['2015-09-25 14:00:00',
                           '2015-09-25 15:00:00']),
    columns=['copy_me'])

# 1. secondary dataframe values have already been computed
# 2. we want to assign them to the primary dataframe for available dates
# 3. once done, we want to return dataframe index locations for missing values
# 4. nan is one of the valid values the secondary dataframe can take

primary['copy_me'] = secondary['copy_me']

print (secondary)
print (primary)

# The values have been copied successfully
# But how to get the locations of missing indices?
# The expected result is as follows:
# If I know these values I could pass them to my computing function

missing_indices = np.array([0,1,4])
print('needed result: ', missing_indices)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this might help:

```
(~primary.index.isin(secondary.index)).nonzero()[0]
```

Breakdown:

1. Find which `primary` indixes are present in `secondary` (`primary.index.isin(secondary.index)`).
2. Negate that condition (`~`).
3. Find positions where value is non-zero, meaning `True`, using [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html). (`.nonzero()[0]`, `[0]` because it returns a tuple)

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if `primary.index` is in `secondary.index`:

```py
np.flatnonzero(~primary.index.isin(secondary.index))
# array([0, 1, 4], dtype=int32)
```